# Emulator: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, android-emulator, build.gradle, abi, android-x86

I tried to install my app into Android9 x86 Device, it failed with error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Added abiFilters and splits abi in gradle, still I'm facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my SingalR libs, when I used latest library from the document, it installed and worked fine. [SingalR](https://github.com/eak65/FixedSignalRJar)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the following two things.

1. You can check the emulator's abi with the following step.

   > Open AVD Manager -> View Detail

   [image]
2. If it's not for x86, you should install the abi with the following step.

   > Open AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device...

   [image]

Comment: yes i have installed it already. I tired with various images also x86_64, no luck

Comment: I see, if you wanna check something for 32bit, how about you try to install armeabi-v7a?

Comment: its working with armeabi-v7a old versions till android 7, its not working with x86 and x 86_64 android 8 & 9